Retrieving secret from Enterprise vault (with custom namespace) is failing with error: vault 403 Forbidden: "{"errors":["permission denied"]}<EOL>
Deployed and configured vault using below steps:
1# Deployed helm using Enterprise trial license in k8 cluster(namespace: k8ns)
kubectl create secret generic vault-ent-license --from-literal="license=${secret}"
helm install hashicorp hashicorp/vault -f config.yaml -n k8ns

2# Initialized vault and unsealed keys
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault operator init -format=json
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault operator unseal key1
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault operator unseal key2
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault operator unseal key3

3# Performed vault login
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault login <root token>

4# Created vault namespace
created vault namespace(vaultns) from vault UI
5# Created secret engine kv and created ACL policy
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault secrets enable -namespace="vaultns" -version=2 -path=kv kv

Added policy(k8s_test) with below capabilities
path "kv/*"
{
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}

6# Kubernetes authentication method to use the service account token
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault auth enable -namespace=vaultns  -path="kubernetes" kubernetes
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -n k8ns -- vault write -namespace=vaultns  auth/kubernetes/config token_reviewer_jwt="<service account token>" kubernetes_host=https://kubernetes.k8ns.svc kubernetes_ca_cert=@/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt issuer="https://kubernetes.k8ns.svc.cluster.local"

7# Created roles and added secrets
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -- vault write -namespace=vaultns  auth/kubernetes/role/product bound_service_account_names=hashicorp-vault bound_service_account_namespaces=k8ns policies=k8s_test ttl=1h
kubectl exec hashicorp-vault-0 -- vault kv put -namespace=vaultns  secret/a/product/system/database username=system password=R@spb3rry123

8# Configure vault in application
  vault:
    url: http://hashicorp-vault.k8ns.svc:8200
    namespace: vaultns
    authenticationPath: kubernetes
    secretEngine: kv

9# Below is the Request and headers and error returned:
vaultUri:http://hashicorp-vault.k8ns.svc:8200, serviceName:product
"GET /v1/kv/data/a/product/system/database HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
"Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
"X-Vault-Namespace: vaultns[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
"Host: hashicorp-vault.k8ns.svc:8200[\r][\n]"
"Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.10)[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
"Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
"Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
"X-Vault-Namespace: vaultns[\r][\n]"
"Date: Thu, 09 May 2024 05:22:55 GMT[\r][\n]"
"Content-Length: 33[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"{"errors":["permission denied"]}[\n]"
Exception!!!!! org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: "{"errors":["permission denied"]}<EOL>" Status 403 Forbidden [kv]: permission denied

Followed few related solutions available in forums like below which didn't resolve the issue:

tried with ep, cluster info url for kubernetes_host
tried giving read policy for sys/mounts


Appreciate any help.


Seems like the issue is definitely with permission so try checking the service accounts, roles and policies one more time and try accessing the vault using the curl to check whether the error is from application side or from vault.

I have checked the sa, roles, policies. here is my request, response.
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8200/v1/kv/data/product/a/system/database' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--header 'X-Vault-Namespace: vaultns' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ey...' 
response:
{"errors":["permission denied"]}

Here is my audit log---
"request":{"id":"7...","mount_class":"secret","mount_point":"vaultns/kv/","mount_type":"kv","mount_running_version":"v0.17.0+builtin","namespace":{"id":"e2mJB","path":"vaultns/"},"operation":"read","path":"kv/data/product/a/system/database","remote_address":"10.1.26.237","remote_port":35912,"request_uri":"/v1/kv/data/product/a/system/database"},"response":{"data":{"error":"hmac-sha256:c853ef7b74f1fafea456105412b814cec427885132bd17806d4baeb8dc2ef0a4"},"mount_class":"secret","mount_point":"vaultns/kv/","mount_running_plugin_version":"v0.17.0+builtin","mount_type":"kv"}}
